# undefined method trying to match string

Tags: ruby

I'm getting an 'undefined method' error on  the get_nums method below, and I can't figure out why. list_hostnames returns an array, but get_nums can't do anything with it. Could someone please point me in the right direction?

```
class Hostname
  attr_accessor :hostname, :domain_controller_ip, :username, :password, :hosts

  def initialize(hostname, domain_controller_ip, ad_username, ad_password)
    @domain_controller_ip = domain_controller_ip
    @ad_username = ad_username
    @ad_password = ad_password
    @hostname = hostname
    @hosts = []

  def list_hostnames
    a = Ldap.new(@domain_controller_ip, @ad_username, @ad_password)
    hostname = @hostname + "*"
    a.ldap_con.search(:base => a.treebase, :filter => a.filter('cn', hostname)) do |entry|
      self.hosts.push(entry.cn[0])
    end
    self.hosts.each do |x|
      p x
    end
  end

  def get_nums
    self.hosts.each do |x|
      i = x.match(/\d+$/)
      p i
    end
end
end

a = Hostname.new('prod-srv-1', '192.168.1.1', 'administrator', 'password')
b = a.list_hostnames
b.get_nums
end
```

Comment: also your `#initialize` method is missing an `end`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems, that you've been confused by indentation and didn't correctly close the methods by `end`.

I think that the following code is the correct version of the code you're trying to implement:

```
class Hostname
  attr_accessor :hostname, :domain_controller_ip, :username, :password, :hosts

  def initialize(hostname, domain_controller_ip, ad_username, ad_password)
    @domain_controller_ip = domain_controller_ip
    @ad_username = ad_username
    @ad_password = ad_password
    @hostname = hostname
    @hosts = []
  end

  def list_hostnames
    a = Ldap.new(@domain_controller_ip, @ad_username, @ad_password)
    hostname = @hostname + "*"
    a.ldap_con.search(:base => a.treebase, :filter => a.filter('cn', hostname)) do |entry|
      self.hosts.push(entry.cn[0])
    end
    self.hosts.each do |x|
      p x
    end

    self
  end

  def get_nums
    self.hosts.each do |x|
      i = x.match(/\d+$/)
      p i
    end
  end
end

a = Hostname.new('prod-srv-1', '192.168.1.1', 'administrator', 'password')
b = a.list_hostnames
b.get_nums
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. I totally missed that. Unfortunately I fixed it and am still getting 'undefined method' 'nomethoderror' on get_nums.

Comment: I corrected the code. The problem is that `list_hostnames` returns an array, rather than instance of `Hostname`.

Comment: return `self` from `list_hostnames` if you want to call `get_nums` on the object, that `list_hostnames` returns

Comment: Thank you Igor! That did it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have an `attr_accessor` defined for `hosts`, you don't need the `self.hosts`. You could just do:

```
hosts.each do |h|
  # code here
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I removed self from my code, and added 'end' to my initialize method, but it still throws the same 'nomethoderror' for get_nums